# synchronizing JIRA with 3rd Party System e.g. Bug tracking system

Tags: jira

I want to synchronize my bug tracking system to JIRA. I use different rest api approaches to get bug information, but do not get appropriate information.

http://example.com:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey} [GET, DELETE, PUT] 
http://example.com:8080/jira/rest/api/2/search [GET, POST]

But both of these can't give me the appropriate information.

And one more these can me protected properties of json, which is not able to parse.

```
[requestLength:protected] => 0
[acceptType:protected] => application/json
[responseBody:protected] => {"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelog", ....
```

Look at protected properties of json.

What I am looking for is:

1. Get latest Status of the bug.
2. Parse protected properties of JSON.

Comment: Do you want to synchronize JIRA with another bug tracking system periodically? One-way or two-way? Or do you just need to import issues from a 3rd party system to JIRA once? Which 3rd party system are you using? Have you considered using a desired product for the synchronization? If so, have you seen [Takstop](http://www.tasktop.com/)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying Jira with Python and Rest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098333/querying-jira-with-python-and-rest)

Comment: No, it isn't. But the question gives no context of the problem (as @harpun has asked) and got no answer yet.